# Make connectivity listener run as long as the phone is on?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, background-service, android-connectivitymanager

I have followed [this](http://clover.studio/2016/09/03/checking-internet-connectivity-in-android/) tutorial  and I got the result where I click the button, the connectivity state is shown (connected to internet or not) and it keeps running for as long as I'm running the app. 
But if I exit, the connectivity listener stops working (I added to the code a toast message whenever the state changes and after exiting no message appears even if I connect and disconnect to internet).
Is there a way to make the listener work for as long as the phone is on ? because I have services to run whenever an internet connection is available.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible any more, for more info take a look at this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBjTXKpaFj8

Comment: If I'm making an app targeting api>=14, do I have to use the "old" method up until api21 and for api>=21, I can use jobscheduler ? because the suggested method in the video is jobscheduler but it's only for api>=21